# Can we define a timeout for the singleton instance in unity container?

Tags: wcf, unity-container

I use `unity` container in my `WCF` service application. NuGet package 5.11.1. Currently I use `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` lifetime manager(singleton) which returns the same object when resolved. 
I want to give a timeout to the lifetime manager so that a new object will be created after a specific time like 2 minutes. Is it possible to do that with unity?

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyConcrete>(); // register the interface
container.Resolve<IMyInterface>(); // it will create the object at first time
container.Resolve<IMyInterface>(); // it will return the same object object
// after 2 minutes 
container.Resolve<IMyInterface>(); // it will create a new object object again
```

Comment: I didn’t use unity in my WCF service application, I would like to know how did you organize your project structure and apply the third-party library. Would you mind sharing your experience on use unity in the WCF service application?

Comment: @AbrahamQian Basically I added `Unity` from `Nuget`. I register all classes with `UnityContainer` in `Application_Start` function of `Global.asax` file. (`RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>` method) Then I resolve the instances with Unity in my service classes. (`Resolve<T>`)

Comment: It's possible, but you will need to create your own custom lifetime manager class. There is nothing that supports this out-of-the-box. I thought of doing this myself some time ago but then it turned out I didn't really need it, so I never got around to doing it.